# Entity Framework database-first : how to add property to a model that will reference itself?

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to create a `Product` table that will have a list of `SubstitutionProducts` that should reference other `Product` from the same table.

Model example :

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsMissing { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> SubstitutionProducts { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Well, you already did it. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to include the parent ID in your model:

```
public class Product
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsMissing { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public Product Parent { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Product> SubStitutionProducts { get; set; }
    }
```

This is how to configure DB schema via overriding OnModelCreatingmethod of your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
           
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOne(x => x.Parent)
                .WithMany(x => x.SubStitutionProducts)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentId).IsRequired(false);

        }
```

Comment: I guess I haven't been clear about what I wanna achieve, so I will do it now.

Let's say you have a list of `products` in the warehouse and one of the `products` go missing. You will have to give an option of the other products that can be used instead.

If your answer is doing just that could you please elaborate why you would need Parent product in the model ?

Comment: Each product, in addition to having  multiple substitutes, can also be a substitute for another product. Instead of the parentID, you can use the substitutedID.

Comment: @Mr.Hat Please add clarifications to your question, do not post them in comments. I asked what's wrong with your model. It's not clear what you're asking and the answer is premature.